# Listview change appearance for selected item

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following ListView

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="175"
        Height="200" Grid.Row="2" Name="StepsList" SelectionMode="Single" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}" Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
        SelectionChanged="StepsList_SelectionChanged"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
   <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn Width="170" Header="Steps">
               <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                      <Grid Width="165" GotFocus="StepsGrid_OnGotFocus"
                          LostFocus="StepsGrid_OnLostFocus">
                         <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                              <ColumnDefinition Width="105"/>
                              <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                              <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                         </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                         <views:EditableTextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                              Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                         <Button Name="StepUp" Grid.Column="1"
                             Content="↑" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                         <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="↓" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                      </Grid>
                  </DataTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
               </GridViewColumn>
               <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                 <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                 </Style>
               </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
            </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Want I want is, that the `Button`s are only visible if the Item is selected and the up/down button to be disabled if the selected Item is is most top/bottom Item in the list. 

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Why would you disable down on the top row?

Comment: I mean, I want to disable the up/down button if the selected Item is the most top/bottom Item.

Comment: @Nabil A. did the suggested answer work for you?

Comment: Your idea works for disabling the Buttons, but not for hiding them if the row/cell is not selected. I'll post what I end up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with the following.
xml

```
<ListView VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="175" Height="200" Grid.Row="2" Name="StepsList" SelectionMode="Single" 
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Steps}"
                      Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.RowSpan="2" SelectionChanged="StepsList_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="170" Header="Steps">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Grid Width="165">
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="105"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="15"/>
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <views:EditableTextBlock Grid.Column="0"  Text="{Binding Number}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                                        <Button Name="StepUp"  Grid.Column="1" Content="↑" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Hidden" Click="StepUp_OnClick"/>
                                        <Button Name="StepDown" Grid.Column="2" Content="↓" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Visibility="Hidden" Click="StepDown_OnClick"/>
                                    </Grid>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn>
                        <GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                            </Style>
                        </GridView.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
```

c#

```
 private void StepsList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _viewModel.SetStep(StepsList.SelectedIndex);

        var gridView = StepsList.View as GridView;
        var listBoxItem = StepsList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(StepsList.SelectedItem) as ListBoxItem;
        var listBoxItems = Enumerable.Range(0, StepsList.Items.Count).Select(x => StepsList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(x) as ListBoxItem);
        var column = gridView.Columns[0];
        Button up;
        Button down;
        foreach (var contentPresenter in listBoxItems.Where(x => x != null).Select(x => x.GetVisualChild<ContentPresenter>()))
        {
            up = column.CellTemplate.FindName("StepUp", contentPresenter) as Button;
            down = column.CellTemplate.FindName("StepDown", contentPresenter) as Button;
            up.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            down.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            up.IsEnabled = true;
            down.IsEnabled = true;
        }

        if (listBoxItem == null) return;
        var myContentPresenter = listBoxItem.GetVisualChild<ContentPresenter>();

        up = column.CellTemplate.FindName("StepUp", myContentPresenter) as Button;
        down = column.CellTemplate.FindName("StepDown", myContentPresenter) as Button;
        if (up == null) return;
        up.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        if (Equals(_viewModel.Steps.First(), StepsList.SelectedItem))
            up.IsEnabled = false;
        if (down == null) return;
        down.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        if (Equals(_viewModel.Steps.Last(), StepsList.SelectedItem))
            down.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using MultiBinding. You may want to adjust the logic, as Blam said, I don't think you really want to disable both buttons in both outer bounds spots, but that's what you said so...

XAML:

```
<Button Name="StepUp"  Grid.Column="1" Content="↑" HorizontalAlignment="Right"  >
                                    <Button.Visibility>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OuterboundsConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="DataContext.Steps" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                                            <Binding></Binding>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Button.Visibility>
                                </Button>
                                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="↓" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                                    <Button.Visibility>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource OuterboundsConverter}">
                                            <Binding Path="DataContext.Steps" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
                                            <Binding></Binding>
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </Button.Visibility>
                                </Button>
```

Converter:

```
public class OuterboundsConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility vis = Visibility.Visible;


        if (values != null)
        {
            ObservableCollection<string> steps = values[0] as ObservableCollection<string>;
            string item = values[1] as string;

            if (steps != null && item != null)
            {
                if (steps.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (steps[0] == item || steps[steps.Count - 1] == item)
                    {
                        vis = Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        return vis;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: make sure to adjust Window to UserControl if this isn't a window etc. in the  Binding Paths, and whatever type of collection you are using, i just used ObservableCollection<string> for my example.  the converter could probably use some more checks to make sure their are the correct number of values[] etc. as well, but you get the idea

Comment: btw, I would assume you'd actually want to have a separate converter for each button.  one for up, one for down, so, for example, the down button would still display when its at the top of the list, but the up button should still display when its at the bottom of the list